# no value given for one or more required parameters insert into error

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am receiving error while inserting data into a table. The error is on below:

> no value given for one or more required parameters.

I tried to fix the problem but was unsuccessful. I appreciate if you help.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Generate

Private Sub Generate_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    txtEmId.Enabled = False
    txtEmName.Enabled = False

    txtIdCtm.Enabled = False
    txtNameCtm.Enabled = False



    btnAddEp.Enabled = False
    btnAddMT.Enabled = False
    btnprintG.Enabled = False
    btnccc.Enabled = False

    sql = "SELECT รหัสวัสดุ FROM วัสดุ "

    If (Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
        Connection.Close()
    End If

    Connection.Open()

    Adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Connection)
    Dataset = New DataSet


    Adapter.Fill(Dataset, "IDMT")

    CbIDMt.DataSource = Dataset.Tables("IDMT")
    CbIDMt.DisplayMember = "รหัสวัสดุ"
    CbIDMt.ValueMember = "รหัสวัสดุ"




    Connection.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancelg.Click
    Dim exg As MsgBoxResult
    exg = MessageBox.Show("ต้องการยกเลิกการผลิตใช่หรือไม่", "ตรวจสอบ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2)
    If exg = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    sql = "SELECT * FROM ลูกค้า INNER JOIN (พนักงาน INNER JOIN คำสั่งซื้อ ON พนักงาน.รหัสพนักงาน = คำสั่งซื้อ.รหัสพนักงาน) ON ลูกค้า.รหัสลูกค้า = คำสั่งซื้อ.รหัสลูกค้า  WHERE เลขที่คำสั่งซื้อ = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"

    'sql = "SELECT * FROM พนักงาน INNER JOIN (ลูกค้า INNER JOIN คำสั่งซื้อ ON ลูกค้า.รหัสลูกค้า = คำสั่งซื้อ.รหัสลูกค้า) ON พนักงาน.รหัสพนักงาน = คำสั่งซื้อ.รหัสพนักงาน WHERE เลขที่คำสั่งซื้อ = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"




    If (Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
        Connection.Close()
    End If

    Connection.Open()

    Command = New OleDbCommand(sql, Connection)
    Reader = Command.ExecuteReader

    Do While Reader.Read

        txtEmId.Text = (Reader(6)).ToString
        txtEmName.Text = (Reader("ชื่อพนักงาน")).ToString
        txtIdCtm.Text = (Reader(0)).ToString
        txtNameCtm.Text = (Reader("ชื่อลูกค้า")).ToString
        TextBox1.Enabled = False
    Loop

    'txtEmId.Text = String.Empty
    'txtEmId.Focus()
    'MessageBox.Show("กรุณากรอกรหัสพนักงานให้ถูกต้อง", "แจ้งเตือน", MessageBoxButtons.OK)




    Reader.Close()



    Connection.Close()





    btnAddMT.Enabled = True


End Sub

Private Sub txtunitMt_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtunitMt.TextChanged



    txtttMt.Text = txtprMt.Text * txtunitMt.Text
End Sub

Private Sub txtunitMt_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtunitMt.KeyPress
    If (e.KeyChar < Chr(48) Or e.KeyChar > Chr(57)) And e.KeyChar <> Chr(8) Then
        e.Handled = True
        MessageBox.Show("กรุณาใส่เฉพาะตัวเลข", "เตือน!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CbIDMt.SelectedIndexChanged

    CbIDMt.Text = String.Empty
    Try

        sql = "SELECT รหัสวัสดุ, ชื่อวัสดุ, ราคาต่อหน่วย, ยอดคงเหลือ FROM วัสดุ WHERE รหัสวัสดุ = '" & CbIDMt.SelectedValue & "'"
        If (Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
            Connection.Close()
        End If

        Connection.Open()

        Command = New OleDbCommand(sql, Connection)
        Reader = Command.ExecuteReader



        Do While Reader.Read
            CbIDMt.SelectedValue = Reader(0).ToString
            txtNameMt.Text = Reader(1).ToString
            txtprMt.Text = Reader(2).ToString
            txtBalance.Text = Reader(3).ToString
        Loop
        Reader.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        Connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnAddMT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddMT.Click
    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(IdGenerate.Text)) Or
        (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IdGenerate.Text)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("กรุณาใส่รหัสใบผลิต")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Connection.Open()

    Dim unitss As Int64 = CInt(IIf(Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtunitMt.Text)),
    txtunitMt.Text, 0))

    Dim prtotal As Int32 = CInt(IIf(Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtprMt.Text)),
    txtprMt.Text, 0))


    Dim totalf As Double = CDbl(IIf(Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtttf.Text)),
    txtttf.Text, 0))

    Dim totalcr As Double = CDbl(IIf(Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtttcr.Text)),
    txtttcr.Text, 0))

    Dim totalsss As Double = CDbl(IIf(Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(totalss.Text)),
    totalss.Text, 0))

    Dim totalmttt As Int32 = CInt(IIf(Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtttMts.Text)),
    txtttMts.Text, 0))

    Dim avgtt As Double = CDbl(IIf(Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtavgtotal.Text)),
    txtavgtotal.Text, 0))


    Dim MySql As String = String.Empty

        '------------- INSERT -------------'
        MySql &= "INSERT INTO ใบสั่งผลิต(เลขที่ใบสั่งผลิต, วันที่สั่งผลิต, รหัสวัสดุ, จำนวน, ราคารวม, ราคารวมทั้งหมดวัสดุ, รหัสพนักงาน, รหัสลูกค้า, เลขที่ใบแจ้งเงินเดือน, จำนวนเงินเดือน, เลขที่ค่าใช้จ่าย, จำนวนเงินค่าใช้จ่าย, รวมทั้งหมด, ราคาต้นทุนเฉลี่ย )"

    MySql &= "VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    MySql &= ",'" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "'"
    MySql &= "," & CbIDMt.SelectedValue.ToString & ""
    MySql &= "," & Convert.ToInt64(unitss)
    MySql &= "," & Convert.ToInt32(prtotal)
    MySql &= "," & Convert.ToInt32(totalmttt)
    MySql &= ",'" & txtEmId.Text & "'"
    MySql &= ",'" & txtIdCtm.Text & "'"
    MySql &= ",'" & txtIdf.Text & "'"
    MySql &= "," & Convert.ToDouble(totalf)
    MySql &= ",'" & txtidcr.Text & "'"
    MySql &= "," & Convert.ToDouble(totalcr)
    MySql &= "," & Convert.ToDouble(totalsss)
    MySql &= "," & Convert.ToDouble(avgtt) & ")"






        Command.CommandText = MySql
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("เพิ่มข้อมูลสำเร็จ", "แจ้งเตือน", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    Connection.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Label19_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label19.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and reduce it to the necessary part to reproduce the problem. The button click handlers are not necessary and the combobox parts can also be deleted. Have you printed your SQL statement `MySql` and verified that it works in the mysql client without your code?

Comment: You'll have a problem if one of your string contains a '. You should definitely look at using parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Please focus on the code part below. Check your table:ใบสั่งผลิต and see what columns are not "nullable" and make sure that some value is set for those fields. Also, make sure the order of rows are matching while inserting. It should be like:

```
Insert into table (col1,col2,...col50) values (col1,col2,...,col50);
```

The code part you need to debug on below. I specified which line goes for which column, please match. If matching is OK, make sure "not null" columns will have a value after execution.

```
MySql &= "INSERT INTO ใบสั่งผลิต (เลขที่ใบสั่งผลิต, วันที่สั่งผลิต, รหัสวัสดุ, จำนวน, ราคารวม, ราคารวมทั้งหมดวัสดุ, รหัสพนักงาน, รหัสลูกค้า, เลขที่ใบแจ้งเงินเดือน, จำนวนเงินเดือน, เลขที่ค่าใช้จ่าย, จำนวนเงินค่าใช้จ่าย, รวมทั้งหมด, ราคาต้นทุนเฉลี่ย )"

MySql &= "VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "'"  //เลขที่ใบสั่งผลิต
MySql &= ",'" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "'"  //วันที่สั่งผลิต
MySql &= "," & CbIDMt.SelectedValue.ToString & "" //รหัสวัสดุ
MySql &= "," & Convert.ToInt64(unitss) //จำนวน
MySql &= "," & Convert.ToInt32(prtotal) //ราคารวม
MySql &= "," & Convert.ToInt32(totalmttt) //ราคารวมทั้งหมดวัสดุ
MySql &= ",'" & txtEmId.Text & "'" //รหัสพนักงาน
MySql &= ",'" & txtIdCtm.Text & "'" //รหัสลูกค้า
MySql &= ",'" & txtIdf.Text & "'" //เลขที่ใบแจ้งเงินเดือน
MySql &= "," & Convert.ToDouble(totalf) //จำนวนเงินเดือน
MySql &= ",'" & txtidcr.Text & "'" //เลขที่ค่าใช้จ่าย
MySql &= "," & Convert.ToDouble(totalcr) //จำนวนเงินค่าใช้จ่าย
MySql &= "," & Convert.ToDouble(totalsss) //รวมทั้งหมด
MySql &= "," & Convert.ToDouble(avgtt) & ")" //ราคาต้นทุนเฉลี่ย
```